# What pattern applies to encapsulating "contextual" queries?

Tags: database, design-patterns, architecture, encapsulation

At the moment, my project at work has a very inefficient loop which is suffering the `n + 1` problem to a great degree.  (`6n + 1`, I think.)  Currently, a number of web services instantiate an object whose constructor builds a canonical representation of one of our ORM objects -- call them `Foo` and `FooView()`.  There are a number of places where a collection of `Foo` is built; each instance of `Foo` is passed to `FooView` and has its (pseudo-)foreign key fields queried in *another database* to build a textual representation, so that, for example, we can return `<fooColor>Blue</fooColor>` rather than `<fooColor>5</fooColor>`.  The sets of these properties--Colors, Shapes, and other similarly general properties--are relatively small, and obviously should be pulled into memory.

There is also another, more complex query, which is contributing to the `6n + 1` problem.  This is a set of metadata fields. Each `Foo` has a `Source`. Each `Source` can have one, none, or many metadata fields defined for their subset of `Foos`. Empty XML tags are required for metadata fields which apply to a given `Foo`'s `Source`.  Currently, the four(!) ORM queries(!) used to build this XML are located inside the `FooView` constructor, meaning they get executed for each and every `Foo`.

My goal is as follows:

1. Query for general properties, like `Color`, `Shapes`, etc. before anything else.
2. Run the query to generate the collection of `Foo`.  Store the primary keys in a list.
3. Using the list of primary keys, run the heinous multi-join, raw SQL query to generate `Foo.Metadata`.
4. Call `FooView`, providing the collection of `Foo` along with a context object containing the items built in steps 1 and 3.  `FooView` will provide the interleaving logic, using the context object rather than database lookups.

Is this a sound practice?  It will certainly solve some of the performance problems in generating the `FooView`, but where should this thing live?  Should I call it `FooHelper`?  `FooContext`?  `FooService`?  Is this a design pattern, or is there one I should be using to make this more logical?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not chatty or open ended. I am asking a specific design question: is there a design pattern which helps me encapsulate this?  All of the information in my question is relevant to the situation and is abstracted to make it more concise and easy to understand.